# How to open localhost port in a new tab for preview in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, editor

I use Prepros, that creates livepreview on any port of localhost, for example "localhost:7881". How can I open this port in a new tab of editor and see all the changes inside Visual Code, not on browser?
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBADm.png)